# Amazon S3 fails uploading of 1000+ files s3 bucket with 403 forbidden after 900 ms

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js

Environment details:

Back end :AWS Amplify

Front end : NextJS

I am implementing a solution where the user need to upload 1000+ individual files ranges from 500mb to 1gb to Amazon S3 bucket from browser every time when user wants to upload, similar to dropbox or Google drive.
Once the files are received, the files are passed to a method where it is iterated using for each loop and the upload is triggered using Amplify Storage.put API.
Everything goes good when upload time is less than 15 min or 900 ms. If the upload process goes beyond 15 min the server stops accepting and fails with 403 forbidden.

Also, i tried using AWS JavaScript sdk's s3.upload api even the behavior is same.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this could be an HttpClient timeout error. Amplify uses an HttpClient process in the background for its API calls. To be sure I have this right, the files are iterated over on the client side and uploaded individually to S3?

Comment: Yes. It is iterated over the client side and uploaded. I even tried changing the httpoptions timeout value more than 900 ms. but no luck.